# win 10 desktop icon text show full length

Tags: windows-10, icons, desktop

How can i reset the desktop icon text to default length?
It shall not overlap other icons!

Problem:
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Rename the file: Drag-select the file. Press F2. Type a short name. Press Enter

Comment: What do you *expect* to happen?

Answer (score 0):

This is default behavior when you click a file on your desktop with a very long filename.

This is a feature which allows you to read the whole filename instead of only a small portion of it.

You can simply click on any other icon on your desktop to reset it:

[image: example]